# Capybara says can't find CSS selector even though I see it

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, assert

Truly befuddled, this is the test output:

```
Failure/Error: page.assert_selector("#borrower cancel")
 Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
   expected to find css "#borrower cancel" but there were no matches
 # ./spec/features/borrow_dashboard_spec.rb:354:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I did a `save_and_open_page` (yes for the right test) and this is the relevant excerpt from the Inspect Element:

[image]

What is happening?! FYI in a similar situation, other tests that look for `#borrowed item` also say it can't be found. I tried putting the id in both `<td>` and `<span>` and then also tried making it one string, e.g., `borrowed_item`. Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id "must not contain any space characters"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AndreyBotalov points out, the problem is with id attribute including spaces, which is not valid html. The best solution would be to fix the id attribute to not use spaces.

If that is not an option, you can use an attribute selector instead of the id selector. In the attribute selector, make sure to include quotations around the id attribute value:

```
page.assert_selector('[id="borrower cancel"]')
```

Comment: ok so that worked for this spec, but i'm curious... i have a lot of other specs where there are spaces, that have still passed. and certainly multiple instances of `click_link 'cancel this'` any thoughts as to what's happening there?

Comment: Unlike with `assert_selector`, you are not passing a CSS-selector to `click_link`. Instead, you are passing the value of the id attribute, which Capybara (or I believe it is the XPath gem) then translates into a valid XPath expression. The XPath generation presumably includes quotations around the attribute values.

Comment: Got it, what about the specs where I do have `page.assert_selector("#something with spaces")`? I'm kind of worried that it's been passing this whole time, but due to some other reason

Comment: You would have to show an example. It is not invalid to have a CSS selector that contains spaces. For example `#something with spaces` would be looking for a `spaces` element that is inside a `with` element that is inside an element with id "something".